# LazyVGrid, List, LazyStacks don't release views from memory?

Tags: swift, swiftui, lazyvgrid, phpicker

I'm playing around with the new photo picker in SwiftUI 2 and I made a simple app to show the imported images in a LazyVGrid but when scrolling down, if I imported around 150 images the app finish all the memory and it crashes (Terminated due to memory issue).

I tried the same with a LazyVStack and List but they have the same problem, I was expecting lazy items to release all the cells that goes off screen from the memory but it doesn't look like it's working.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Here's my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Media: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var image: Image
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var itemProviders: [NSItemProvider] = []

    @State private var showingPhotoPicker: Bool = false
    
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 100, maximum: 100), spacing: 8)
    ]
    
    @State var medias: [Media] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 8) {
                    ForEach(medias) { media in
                        media.image
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                            .clipped()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Images \(medias.count)")
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                loadImages()
            }, label: {
                Text("Import \(itemProviders.count) images")
            }), trailing: Button(action: {
                showingPhotoPicker.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "photo.on.rectangle.angled")
            }))
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingPhotoPicker) {
                MultiPHPickerView(itemProviders: $itemProviders)
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func loadImages() {
        for item in itemProviders {
            if item.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
                item.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { image, error in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        guard let image = image as? UIImage else {
                            return
                        }
                        medias.append(Media(image: Image(uiImage: image)))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the PhotoPickerView:

```
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI

struct MultiPHPickerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    
    @Binding var itemProviders: [NSItemProvider]
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> PHPickerViewController {
     
        var configuration = PHPickerConfiguration()
        configuration.filter = .images
        configuration.selectionLimit = 0
        
        let controller = PHPickerViewController(configuration: configuration)
        controller.delegate = context.coordinator
        return controller
        
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController( _ uiViewController: PHPickerViewController, context: Context) {}
    
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
        
        @Environment(\.presentationMode)  private var presentationMode
        
        var parent: MultiPHPickerView
        
        init( _ parent: MultiPHPickerView ) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
            
            picker.dismiss( animated: true )
            
            self.parent.itemProviders = results.map(\.itemProvider)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Have you solution for this?

Comment: LazyV/H/Stacks/Grids are only loading the view lazily but they don't free it from memory. 
The only scroll view in SwiftUI that currently does that is the `List`. But this doesn't work great with LazyGrids either as it has the same problem. Even worse, it's loading all cells on appear. 
So best solution would be to chunk your data in pieces and create rows with more than one image

Comment: This would help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/78138473/23574168