# Local database load images, but the memory grows infinitely and memory overflow - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, database, caching, swiftui, memory-management

//Problem is already solve and the code below is already changed, please feel free to consume the following codes

The memorize is good for know, usually keep in 50MB, never bigger than 100MB.

- Use LazyView to show images
- When images appear add new images, when the amount bigger than max images amount, delete the old images
- Use @ObjectState and @Published to really delete the images from  memory.

In my SwiftUI program, I'm observing an unbounded increase in memory usage as images are loaded from a local database (simulate now, original is used by SQLite3) and displayed to the user. As more images are loaded during scrolling, memory isn't being reclaimed, causing a continuous growth in memory consumption. This behavior suggests a memory leak, leading to potential memory overflow.

MainView:

```
import SwiftUI

let triggerLoadNumber = 5 // How many items from the edge should trigger loading
let batchSize = 10 // Number of items to load per batch
let maxContentCount = 20 // Maximum number of content items to hold in memory

struct ScrollShowView: View {
  @Binding var bookName: String
  @StateObject var imageLoader = ImageLoader()
  
  // The load threshold, presumably used to determine when to start loading new content
  private let loadThreshold = 100.0
  
  var body: some View {
    if !imageLoader.showImages.isEmpty {
      ScrollView {
        LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
          ForEach(imageLoader.ids, id: \.self) { id in
            Group {
              // Attempt to find the view content by ID
              if let viewContent = imageLoader.showImages.first(where: { $0.id == id }) {
                Image(uiImage: viewContent.image!)
                  .resizable()
                  .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                  .onAppear {
                    imageLoader.bookName = bookName
                    // Get the index of the current image
                    if let index: Int = imageLoader.showImages.firstIndex(of: viewContent) {
                      // Check if we need to load more content based on scroll position
                      if index < triggerLoadNumber - 1 {
                        // User has scrolled near the top, load previous content
                        imageLoader.loadMoreViewContent(direction: .previous)
                      } else if index > imageLoader.showImages.count - triggerLoadNumber {
                        // User has scrolled near the bottom, load next content
                        imageLoader.loadMoreViewContent(direction: .next)
                      }
                    }
                  }
              } else {
                // Display a loading placeholder if image is not available
                Image("Loading")
                  .resizable()
                  .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                  .onAppear {
                    imageLoader.bookName = bookName
                    imageLoader.doubleDirectionsLoadViewContent(for: id) {}
                  }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      Image("Loading")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .onAppear {
          imageLoader.bookName = bookName
          imageLoader.loadInitialContent()
        }
    }
  }
}

class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {
  @State var bookName: String = ""
  @Published var ids: [Int] = []
  @Published var showImages: [RPViewContent] = []
  @Published var isLoading = false
  
  // Load the initial set of images
  func loadInitialContent() {
    isLoading = true
    // Fetch all page IDs from the book
    ids = BooksDatabase().getAllIds(from: bookName)
    // Load the initial batch of content based on maxContentCount
    let initialIndexes = Array(ids.prefix(maxContentCount))
    singleDirectionLoadViewContent(for: initialIndexes, direction: .next) {
      self.isLoading = false
    }
  }
  
  // Enum to define the direction of content loading
  enum LoadDirection {
    case previous, next
  }
  
  // Load more content in the given direction
  func loadMoreViewContent(direction: LoadDirection) {
    guard !isLoading else { return }
    isLoading = true
    
    // Determine the ID of the relevant content based on the direction of loading
    let relevantId: Int?
    switch direction {
    case .previous:
      relevantId = showImages.first?.id
    case .next:
      relevantId = showImages.last?.id
    }
    
    // Ensure the ID is valid and determine the new range of IDs to load
    guard let id = relevantId, let index = ids.firstIndex(of: id) else {
      isLoading = false
      return
    }
    
    let newIndexes: [Int]
    switch direction {
    case .previous:
      // Load the previous batch of content
      let start = max(0, index - batchSize)
      newIndexes = Array(ids[start..<index])
    case .next:
      // Load the next batch of content
      let end = min(ids.count, index + batchSize)
      newIndexes = Array(ids[index..<end])
    }
    
    // Load the content for the new range of IDs
    singleDirectionLoadViewContent(for: newIndexes, direction: direction) {
      // After loading new content, adjust the currently held content based on the maxContentCount
      switch direction {
      case .previous:
        if self.showImages.count > maxContentCount {
          // If the maximum number is exceeded, remove the trailing elements
          self.showImages.removeLast(self.showImages.count - maxContentCount)
        }
      case .next:
        if self.showImages.count > maxContentCount {
          // If the maximum number is exceeded, remove the header element
          self.showImages.removeFirst(self.showImages.count - maxContentCount)
        }
      }
      self.isLoading = false
    }
  }
  
  // Function to load view content for the specified IDs and handle the completion
  func singleDirectionLoadViewContent(for ids: [Int], direction: LoadDirection, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    // Fetch the original images from the database for the specified IDs
    BooksDatabase().getOriginal(at: ids, from: bookName) { newImages in
      // Insert or append new images to the showImages array based on the direction
      if direction == .previous {
        // Loading content to be displayed above the current content
        self.showImages.insert(contentsOf: newImages, at: 0)
      } else {
        // Loading content to be displayed below the current content
        self.showImages.append(contentsOf: newImages)
      }
      // Call the completion handler
      completion()
    }
  }
  
  func doubleDirectionsLoadViewContent(for id: Int, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    // Calculate the range of IDs to load
    let halfRange = maxContentCount / 2
    let startIdIndex = max(0, id - halfRange)
    let endIdIndex = min(self.ids.count, id + halfRange)
    let loadImagesIds: [Int] = Array(self.ids[startIdIndex..<endIdIndex])
    // Load images for the calculated range of IDs
    BooksDatabase().getOriginal(at: loadImagesIds, from: bookName) { images in
      self.showImages = images
    }
    
    // Call the completion handler
    completion()
  }
}
```

Simulated Database:

```
class BooksDatabase {
  func getOriginal(at pages: [Int], from bookName: String, completion: @escaping ([RPViewContent]) -> Void) {
    let showImages = pages.compactMap { i -> RPViewContent? in
      guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: String(i), ofType: "jpg") else { return nil }
      let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)
      return RPViewContent(id: i, imageType: .clear, image: image)
    }
    
    completion(showImages)
  }
  
  func getAllIds() -> [Int] {
    return Array(0...300)
  }
}
```

Definitions:

```
struct Quadrilateral: Codable {
  var topLeft: CGPoint
  var topRight: CGPoint
  var bottomRight: CGPoint
  var bottomLeft: CGPoint
}

enum POSType: String, Codable {
  case noun
  case verb
  case adjective
  case adverb
  case pronoun
  case preposition
  case conjunction
  case interjection
  case determiner
  case other
  
  var stringValue: String {
    switch self {
    case .noun: return "noun"
    case .verb: return "verb"
    case .adjective: return "adjective"
    case .adverb: return "adverb"
    case .pronoun: return "pronoun"
    case .preposition: return "preposition"
    case .conjunction: return "conjunction"
    case .interjection: return "interjection"
    case .determiner: return "determiner"
    case .other: return "other"
    }
  }
}

struct Word: Codable {
  var texts: String
  var pos: POSType
}

enum ShowingImageType {
  case clear
  case mark
}

//RP = ReadingPage
struct RPInfo: Codable {
  var texts: [Word]?
  var positions: [[Quadrilateral]]?
  var unknowWordsIndex: [Int]?
  var learningWordsIndex: [Int]?
  var definitions: [String:[POSType:[String]]]?
}

struct RPViewContent: Equatable {
  let id: Int
  var imageType: ShowingImageType
  var image: UIImage?
}
```

1. autoreleasepool {} //didn't work for memory
2. LazyVStack -> VStack //didn't work in showing view, also didn't know about memory
3. try to use the way from https://fatbobman.com/en/posts/memory-usage-optimization/, but didn't work

Comment: Looks like the profiler is your friend: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/gathering-information-about-memory-use.

Comment: Not sure but you seem to recreate a lots of time the array during loading which may redraw the view which may relief the image … I would suggest to have the images in a view model that would handle the image loading and image caching in its array.

Comment: I found the reason: I stored the file in Assets.xcassets before, but Assets.xcassets was automatically cached, so there was a problem. Now I changed the DataBase acquisition method to UIImage(contentsOfFile: path), which was very successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Assets.xcassets" Will be cached automatically

```
class BooksDatabase {
  func getOriginal(at pages: [Int], completion: @escaping ([RPViewContent]) -> Void) {
    let showImages = pages.compactMap { i -> RPViewContent? in
      guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: String(i), ofType: "jpg") else { return nil }
      let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)
      return RPViewContent(id: i, imageType: .clear, image: image)
    }
    
    completion(showImages)
  }
...
}
```